# Get substring from List

Tags: python, regex, list

I'm trying to search in an email body for specific lines. I have been able to get an extract the entire email body.  Now I want to extract specific lines from it. My code so far:

```
resp, items = conn.uid("search",None, 'All')
items = items[0].split()
for emailid in items:
    resp, data = conn.uid("fetch",emailid, "(RFC822)")
    if resp == 'OK':
        email_body = data[0][1].decode('utf-8')
        mail = email.message_from_string(email_body)
        if mail["Subject"].find("PA1") > 0 or mail["Subject"].find("PA2") > 0:

           regex = r"(\bEvent demon log entry:)(?:\r?\n|\r)+(\[[^]]+\].*)"
           a=re.findall(regex, email_body , re.IGNORECASE)
```

I'm getting these lines now:

```
[(u'Event demon log entry:', u'[27/12/2018 05:29:30]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: ALARM            ALARM: JO=\r')]
[(u'Event demon log entry:', u'[27/12/2018 04:58:05] CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: ALARM ALARM: JOBFAILURE JOB: p2=\r')]
[(u'Event demon log entry:', u'[27/12/2018 06:00:03]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: ALARM            ALARM: JO=\r')]
[(u'Event demon log entry:', u'[27/12/2018 07:00:05]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: ALARM            ALARM: JO=\r')]
```

but want to get everything between `[(u'Event demon log entry:', u'[27/12/2018 05:29:30]` and `EVENT: ALARM            ALARM: JO=\r')]`

**Desired Output:**

`CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT`

Original Code from email body:

```
Event demon log entry:

[27/12/2018 04:48:17]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: ALARM            ALARM: JOBFAILURE       JOB: bx_p2_reporting EXITCODE:  1
```

**UPDATE:**

Turned out i need to get following:

```
JOB: bx_p2_reporting EXITCODE:  1
```

from

```
Event demon log entry:

[26/12/2018 20:17:14] CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: ALARM ALARM: JOBFAILURE JOB: p2=
_batch_excel_RevalFutBasisSpdCalc_NY3pm MACHINE: ldnmdsbatchxl01 EXITCODE: =
268438455
```

Comment: Use `string_name.[string_name.find(']')+1:string_name.find('EVENT:')]`

Comment: Probably, `regex = r'Event demon log entry:[\r\n]*\[[^]]+]\s*(.*?)\s*EVENT: ALARM'` will do.

Comment: If you post your example input data, that'd be helpful for looking at your regex.

Comment: just posted, thanks

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, unfortunately, doesn't work: [(u'Event demon log entry:\r\n\r\n[27/12/2018 03:10:06]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: ALARM', u'CAUAJM_I_40245')]

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/sn1mGw/1. If you use it with `re.findall`, you should only get `CAUAJM_I_40245`. If you use `re.search`, grab `match.group(1)`.

Comment: It's not the best regex in the world, but this seems to work okay: 

(?:\bEvent demon log entry:)(?:\r?\n|\r)+(?:\[[^]]+\])(.+)(?:: ALARM.+)

Comment: Ah, you wrapped my regex with `(...)`. Don't do that, remove the outer parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
r'Event demon log entry:[\r\n]*\[[^]]+]\s*(.*?)\s*EVENT: ALARM'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sn1mGw/1/)

If you use it with `re.findall`, you should only get `CAUAJM_I_40245`.

**Details**

- `Event demon log entry:` - a literal substring
- `[\r\n]*` - 0+ CR Or LF symbols
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^]]+` - 1 or more chars other than `]`
- `]` - a `]` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `(.*?)` - Grouop 1: any zero or more chars, other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `EVENT: ALARM` - a literal substring.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/RMMhi3):

```
import re
rx = r"Event demon log entry:[\r\n]*\[[^]]+]\s*(.*?)\s*EVENT: ALARM"
s = "Event demon log entry:\n\n[27/12/2018 04:48:17]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: ALARM            ALARM: JOBFAILURE       JOB: bx_p2_reporting EXITCODE:  1"
print(re.findall(rx, s, re.IGNORECASE))
# => ['CAUAJM_I_40245']
```

Comment: sorry Wiktor, turned out i have now to extact job name and exit code: `From Event demon log entry:

[27/12/2018 04:48:17]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: ALARM            ALARM: JOBFAILURE       JOB: bx_p2_reporting EXITCODE:  1` to get `JOB: bx_p2_reporting EXITCODE:  1`, i'm struggling with generator you sent but can't figure it out

Comment: Unfortunately, getting nothing :(   `regex = r"Event demon log entry:[\r\n]*\[[^]]+]\s*(.*?)\s*EVENT: ALARM.*?JOB:\s*(\S+)\s*EXITCODE:\s*(\d+)" a=re.findall(regex,email_body, re.IGNORECASE) print a` need only `JOB: bx_p2_reporting EXITCODE: 1`

Comment: @xerks No idea, with your current input, [it works well](https://ideone.com/R3XRZQ), it extracts all the data.

Comment: `Event demon log entry:

[27/12/2018 01:18:39] CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: ALARM ALARM: JOBFAILURE JOB: p2_creditriskreporter_generate_lnclose_cob MACHINE: p2prog06 EXITCODE: 1`

Comment: still nothing,could you just give me example how to get job name:p2_creditriskreporter_generate_lnclose_cob ?

Comment: @xerks A string? A list? `JOB:\s*(\S+)`? https://regex101.com/r/sn1mGw/4?

Comment: String is better, if not possible then list

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help, i'm good now,happy holidays !!